# Не работает Toast

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь программировать на Андроид. Часто использовал Тосты. Вначале все было хорошо, но в один "прекрасный день" Тосты из моих активити перестали выводится. Подчеркиваю, код вывода тостов я не менял и студия никаких ошибок не фиксирует. При этом Тосты системных классов продолжают выводиться нормально. В чем может быть причина. Использую Андроид студию последней версии. В старых проектах (более простых этой проблемы нет).

P.S.
Я понимаю, что вопрос задан в достаточно общем виде, но я надеялся, что кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной ситуацией. Возможно я фантазирую, но я полагал что у тоста есть какие-то флаги или условия, которые я как-то зацепил (но они мне не известны) или он конфликтует с другими классами. Вызов тостов у меня стандартный:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

или

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Параметры успешно    сохранены",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
toast.show();
```

Эти участки кода просто "проскакиваются" без каких либо последствий.
Выложить весь проект нереально: десятки активити и ни в одной тосты не работают, хотя раньше РАБОТАЛИ, но ни вызовы ни даже некоторые целые классы с ними я не изменял. Как подробнее объяснить я не знаю - извините.

P.S.
Создал тестовое пустое активити, вызываю его из Main

```
    public void goTest(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), test.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

вот само активити:

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Параметры успешно сохранены",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
    toast.show();
  }
}
```

Эффект тот же.

Comment: @pavlofff, а что не так в вопросе? Перестали работать тосты. Код обычный, работал, не менял. Зачем закрывать?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `getApplicationContext()` на `this`

Comment: Я это пробовал, даже в вышеприведенном тесте, не помогает

Comment: Никаких объективных причин для такого поведения видимо нет. Скорее всего это какой-то глюк. Почистите кэш IDE: invalidate cash, clean project, отключите Instant Run, удалите тестируемое приложение с устройства/эмулятора и прочие такие шаманства

Comment: А лучше вообще переустановить студию. Или ваще винду

Comment: Винда тут точно не причем, Что касается студии, то у меня были на нее подозрения, тем более, что в период "исчезновения" тостов я ее апгрейдил, но простые мои приложения как старые так и новые работают в этой части нормально. Я думал, что может проблема в андроиде моего телефона, но другие приложения в том числе и мои также работают нормально. То что ни у кого подобная проблема не возникала означает ее индивидуальность и мало шансов, что дистанционно кто-то сможет помочь.У меня появилась идея как искать, если получится понять причину поделюсь опытом. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Создал новый проект. Перенес, а по сути скопировал в него все файлы и ресурсы из старого проекта. Делал поэтапно, надеясь выявить проблему - ничего не обнаружил, в старом проекте на этой же студии тосты не работают, в новом все нормально. Единственное обстоятельство - в процессе разработки я обновлял студию и возможно причина именно в этом. Мой совет не обновляйте инструменты в процессе разработки. Извините за беспокойство. Вопрос можно закрывать.